# Databinding a multiselect ListBox in a FormView control

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, listbox, formview, multi-select

I have a multiselect ListBox within a FormView. I can't figure out how to setup the databinding for it.
I can populate the listbox fine.
If the listbox was a single select I could use say `SelectValue='<%#Bind("col")%>'` and that works fine.
Is there something that I can bind to for a multiselect listbox?
I've tried manually DataBinding by handling the DataBinding event of the listbox and setting the selected property on the appropriate items.  Unfortunately, there are no items in the listbox during the DataBinding event.
The closest thing I've found is to save the value that determines what items should be selecting during DataBinding and then use that value in the FormViews DataBinding event to select the right items which seems like a hack to me.

Is there a better way?

---

### EDIT:

To clarify what I am currently doing...

I am using the FormViews's ItemCreated event to save the FormView's DataItem.
Then in the FormView's DataBound event I find the listbox and manually set the selected items. 
It doesn't seem right that I have to save the value like this and I assume there is a more correct way to do this that I just can't see.

Comment: Did you ever come to a solution for this? I have the same problem. I've written the code to loop through the lsitbox items and select the proper once from a datacontext, but then I lose the "magic" two-way binding that I would have had for a dropdown with SelectedValue='<%#Bind("col")%>'

Comment: If I did I don't remember it.  This was over two years ago and a month before I started my current job and I don't really remember the issue.  I assume I left it with the work around I didn't like since I usually come back an update these things if I figure them out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx) event?

Comment: That is for the ListView control.  I'm using a ListBox in a FormView control.

Answer (score 0):

When I've done this in the past I've set the data source of the listbox, bind it, then iterate through the list of items in the listbox and set the .Selected to true for each item that matches my criteria or values.  I'm not sure it's the most efficient, but for the small lists I've dealt with it certainly worked fine.

Comment: That is what I do now but I have to do it during the FormView's DataBound event because the items aren't there in the listbox's DataBinding event. 
Where do you do it?

Comment: Depending on the situation I'd probably call the loadList() function during the page load (making sure it's not a postback), then in the loadList() function do the databinding.  Right after the databinding, in the same loadList() function, then iterate through the list and mark the ones you need.

Comment: I just made a form needing to handle M:N relationships with my database. I did this same thing, except I just did it all in FormView_DataBound event. This would be a good case for a better ListBox/CheckBoxList control that handles multiple value binding.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was abandoning the ListBox all together and I settled on a [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx), as it actually served my purposes better.

Before that though I did write this function to select the current items and I called it from Page_PreRender because binding is complete then, and I could get the controls I needed.

```
    protected void SelectCategories()
    {

        ListBox lb = (ListBox)fvProduct.FindControl("lstCategory");

        Product product = (Product)pdc.Products.Where(a => a.Sku == txtSku.Text).FirstOrDefault();
        var c = pdc.ProductCategories.Where(b => b.ProductId == product.ProductId);

        if (lb != null && lb.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ProductCategory cat in c)
            {
                foreach (ListItem li in lb.Items)
                {
                    if (cat.CategoryId == Convert.ToInt32(li.Value))
                    {
                        li.Selected = true;
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

And then when I need to update from the ListBox I called the following code from the FormView.ItemUpdating event.

```
protected void UpdateCategories()
{
    ListBox lb = (ListBox)fvProduct.FindControl("lstCategory");

    Product product = (Product)pdc.Products.Where(a => a.Sku == txtSku.Text).FirstOrDefault();

    if (lb != null && lb.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (ListItem li in lb.Items)
        {
            ProductCategory pc = new ProductCategory();
            pc = (ProductCategory)pdc.ProductCategories.Where(d => d.CategoryId == Convert.ToInt32(li.Value) && d.ProductId == product.ProductId).FirstOrDefault();

            if (pc == null)
            {
                if (li.Selected == true)
                {
                    //note: if li is selected but pc is null then insert new record .
                    pc = new ProductCategory();
                    pc.ProductId = product.ProductId;
                    pc.CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(li.Value);
                    pdc.ProductCategories.InsertOnSubmit(pc);
                    pdc.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (li.Selected == false)
                {
                    //note: if li is not selected but pc is not null then remove record.
                    pdc.ProductCategories.DeleteOnSubmit(pc);
                    pdc.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This was really bad perfomance-wise, but it did work. Maybe I could have improved it if I [compiled the linq query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx), but I never got that far.  I understand from your comment above that you might have settled on your own workaround to the problem so I am only adding this answer in case it may help future lost souls such as myself.

In the end a TreeView was a better tool for me so I didn't need to do this anyway.  Although that began a new adventure, as you can't easily bind a TreeView to a LinqDataSource, but that is a tale for another day.